# Error while bootstrapping cmake

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Here's the error I get when running ./bootstrap

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.6.1, Copyright 2000-2016 Kitware, Inc.
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.

---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /home2/virionrp/cmake-3.6.1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
```

Here's what the log says:

```
Checking for GNU toolchain
Try: gcc
Line: gcc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied
Test failed to compile
Checking for Clang toolchain
Try: clang
Line: clang  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: clang: command not found
Test failed to compile
Checking for XL toolchain
Try: xlc
Line: xlc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: xlc: command not found
Test failed to compile
Checking for PGI toolchain
Try: pgcc
Line: pgcc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: pgcc: command not found
Test failed to compile
Checking for PathScale toolchain
Try: pathcc
Line: pathcc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: pathcc: command not found
Test failed to compile
Try: cc
Line: cc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)
int main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char* argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc-1;
}

------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: /usr/bin/cc: Permission denied
Test failed to compile
Try: gcc
Line: gcc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)
int main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char* argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc-1;
}

------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied
Test failed to compile
Try: xlc
Line: xlc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)
int main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char* argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc-1;
}

------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: xlc: command not found
Test failed to compile
Try: icc
Line: icc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)
int main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char* argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc-1;
}

------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: icc: command not found
Test failed to compile
Try: tcc
Line: tcc  cmake_bootstrap_117682_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_117682_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)
int main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char* argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc-1;
}

------------------------------------------
./bootstrap: line 572: tcc: command not found
Test failed to compile
```

I'm really not good with this stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `./bootstrap: line 572: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied`: apparently you have a problem with the GCC binary permissions. Don't know redhat so this might be normal, but you need to be allowed to compile something if you are to build cmake.

Comment: you dont have a c/c++ compiler installed on your machine. try `$ whereis gcc` or `$gcc --version` to see if you have the compiler. If not, you have to install it

Comment: and you install with `$ sudo yum install gcc*`

Comment: I don't seem to have permission for the gcc. How do I add permissions for it?

Comment: @LukasClausson maybe try `sudo chmod 777 -R <whereGCCis>`

Comment: I don't think I have gcc. And for some reason I can't install it using a sudo or yum command.

Comment: When I try to use the sudo command I get this error:

sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?


and when I try to use any yum command I get this:


CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

I don't even have a yum config file in my etc

Comment: You would notre get a permission denied error if gcc compiler is not installed, but a command not found instead as for some compiler results. I think you may be missing write or execute permission on the temp folder used by bootstrap tool.

Comment: @A.Loiseau And how would I go about fixing that?